# Set Magento Shipping Method on Product Level

Tags: shipping, extensions, shipping-methods

I am looking for the settings or an extension for shipping. Let me explain.

I have products that are shipped by the post. Thats not the problem. I also have products that can only be picked up at the shop, this is the problem.

When I add a product that can only be picked up at the shop the shipping with post and pickup option are both displayed during checkout.

How can I limit the shipping methods for a particular product in the checkout to only display the pickup at the shop method?

I hope I explained my problem correctly.

Comment: I think the only way to restrict shipping methods is to use and extension. I know that there is one called shipping restrictions

Comment: @Miche van den Hoek Got any solution?

Comment: checked your requirement the [store pickup](https://www.mageants.com/store-pickup-extension-for-magento-2.html) module will work but need some customization in extension

Answer (score 1):

As DaleZA has pointed out there is a module that allows restricting shipping rates given certain rules called [Shipping Restrictions by Amasty](https://amasty.com/shipping-restrictions.html), I've no affiliation to the company - I've simply used the module before and it worked well, however it is a paid option ($99). Essentially it allows you to define conditions (as you would with shopping cart promotions or catalog promotions) to restrict shipping rates.

This is just my experience though, no doubt there are free alternatives that could be better than the above, but I've not used them.

Answer (score 0):

So:

Customers can buy anything and select the 'collect in store option'.

For a subset of the products there is the option to have the item sent out in the post.

There needs to be a requirement to tell the customers that a product is 'collect in store' only. The easiest way to do this is to have another product attribute that is 'collect in store'. In that way the catalog is obvious and easy to maintain by someone other than you.

Collect in store is also the same conceptually as 'free shipping'. If you want to avoid making yet another module you could just have the free shipping method's label re-arranged as per this article here:

http://www.laceytechsolutions.co.uk/ecommerce-development/how-to-add-store-pick-up-to-magento/

Now you can add a shopping cart sales rule to make 'free shipping' condition as per the rules you set. Everything then just works with no coding involved. That does compromise your 'free shipping' options in the future though.

To go modular you can use some other module as a starting point. This one is pretty good for that:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multi-flat-shipping-1.html

You can change the logic for whether the method gets shown or not. This could work on a newly added attribute or do some other function on the cart products.

Comment: THX for the comment i going to try this...

Comment: i have try but i do something wrong....  http://i1293.photobucket.com/albums/b599/Michel_van_den_Hoek/Capture_zpsgbj5smvj.png

Answer (score 0):

I understood your problem and I want to suggest one module which is previously done. You can take a reference from that and can design a new shipping method only for Pickup Orders.

I am providing the link below.

[check this out](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/14/magento-create-custom-shipping-method/)